# How to not display a layer, if its below a other semi transparent layer?

Tags: qgis, postgis, polygon

I have two polygon layers (PostGIS). One of them is semi transparent. If the other layer is below the semi-transparent one, it should **not be displayed**. My situation at the moment is: [image]

The grey buildings outside the red (semi transparent) area should be displayed, the ones inside should not.

I can not physically edit the layers and have to find a "display-solution" with rules or something.

Comment: you could create a series of 'carto-views' that exclude features you want to hide that intersect the ones you want to show...

Comment: I've got to admit, I'm having an issue with wanting a "semi transparent" layer to be opaque.  It sounds like you just need to review your rendering rules.